# How to keep my DbContext in another project?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, convention-over-configur

I'm trying to use EF 6 with Custom Conventions but the interface `IConfigurationConvention` is not recognized!

Packages:

> EntityFramework                6.0.0-beta1-20702

I'm following [this post](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions) but unsuccessfully to use Custom Conventions in EF6